# Uncaught TypeError: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t]: Cannot set property '_injector' of undefined

Tags: angular, build, platform

The source contains a rest API call as well as global variable reference also I have used only bootstrap CSS and not saved jquery since I m not using bootstrap.js
I am getting prod build files after executing(ng build -prod) and everything is working fine on my local server. However, when the same I am merging into JSP code on some other server, I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t]:
Cannot set property '_injector' of undefined"

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  }

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
   
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }

Comment: Can anyone help with the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had same issues, this issue is because of conflict of angular library js files with the jsp or html scripts where you might have merged ur angular code.... please check if there are some prototype methods which will be overwriting angular core files...

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

from app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
...
imports:[HttpClientModule, HttpModule]
```

As taken from these people on github.  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20096

Seems something is still using HttpModule, even though you most likely have switched to HttpClient.

Hope it works for you.